# How to create an geofencing application using dart?

Tags: java, flutter, dart, flutter-platform-channel

I want to build an geofencing application in flutter. But I am not finding a way to create geofence from dart so I'm doing platform-channels from java->dart. Is there any other way to create geofence in flutter. Most of the plugins of geofence in flutter does not work properly. So I want to create a geofence application from scratch. Please give me some reference regrading it any tutorials, codes samples, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't try much but I find one Url or API which may help you

[GeoFance for Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/geofence)

Also, you can add it by adding a dependency in **pubspec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  geofence: ^1.0.3
```

And importing

```
import 'package:geofence/geofence.dart';
```

Take a look in example sample from url site.

Comment: Okay, I will inform you if any other solution will find.

Comment: Sure, please do!

Comment: android only support for this solutions, I suggest to take a look at geofencing 0.0.1 plugin - https://pub.dev/packages/geofencing